# Are there connected subsets of R2 disconnected when the boundary is removed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Give an example of a subset E of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that E is connected but E - ∂E is not connected. Is this possible in $\mathbb{R}$?

I am just learning connectedness and am not quite sure how it works. Does the example of two closed circles intersecting at the origin satisfy the first condition? Similarly, does E = $(-\infty,0] \cup [0,\infty) $ satisfy the second condition? I think it holds by the same logic, but the notation doesn't look right. Advice on how to approach this in the future would be appreciated!

Comment: Your $E$ is just the entire real line. When you say "closed circles," I think you mean closed *disks* ... Does this not satisfy both conditions?

Comment: To add to @TedShifrin, you would want some subset $E$ such that there are limit points $P \in \partial E$ connecting two otherwise disjoint connected subsets.

Comment: @Imeninato Please explain yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\: | \: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\} \cup \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2\:| x \in [1,2]\:\}\cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\: | \: (x-3)^2+y^2 \leq 1\}.$$ Then $E$ is an connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but $$E-\partial E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\: | \: x^2+y^2 < 1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\: | \: (x-3)^2+y^2 < 1\}$$ is not a connected subset. For better understanding you can draw figures for $E$ and $E -\partial E$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Two closed circles (discs) interesting at origin satisfy the first condition. Also, $(-\infty, 0]\cup [0,\infty)=\mathbb{R}$ and $\partial \mathbb{R}=\phi$, hence this set does not satisfy the second condition. In $\mathbb{R}$ with usual topology, only connecting sets are singletons and intervals (open, closed, semi-open-close, infinite intervals). If we remove an interval boundary, it remains the connected set. This is not possible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What about E = (-1,0]∪(0,1)?  It's E−∂E I believe is (-1,0)∪(0,1) which is disconnected.

Comment: Here $E=(-1,0] \cup (0,1)=(-1,1)$ therefore $E-\partial E=(-1,1)$, which is connected.